# How to use dolphinscheduler with AWS EMR

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

We have installed Dolphinscheduler 1.3 on a cluster of 2 ec2 instances. We would like to run a scheduled flink job.

We have an AWS EMR cluster and we have Flink running on it.

How can I have DS manage jobs on the EMR cluster? The only worker group I see on DS is the "default" worker group, which contains the 2 instances we installed DS on.

Answer (score 0):

you can config the worker groups in the conf/worker.properties,

```
worker.groups=default,wokergroup1,workergroup2,xxx,...
```

then restart the worker server process

if your configuration works, you will see the all worker group names on the UI:
 [image about all work group names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQqn.png)

Comment: hi, @swagrov, did you solve your problem? DolphinScheduler community has slack channel, you also can ask quesions : https://s.apache.org/dolphinscheduler-slack